# Flagging as spam reduces an answer's score; shouldn't that also reduce the user's reputation?

Tags: support, flags, spam

I have flagged [an answer on Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12130/drupal-birt-integration/15278#15278) as spam; the answer got an automatic down-vote, but the reputation of the user didn't change, while I was used to the reputation being reduced because the automatic down-vote. This is not the first time I have noticed this.

I have looked for a question here on meta, but I didn't find anything. Was this recently changed, or is it supposed to work as before?

Comment: I wanted to [close this as a duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work), but then I realized what you really asked.

Comment: Oh, I just realised...You would expect the -1 vote to affect the score immediately but instead it doesn't. I get you now.

Comment: @Asylum Yeah, I didn't choose a good title. Thanks to you, the title is much better, and less confusing.

Comment: @tombull89 Yes, that is correct. At least, that is what I previously observed.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Are you sure that there should be an apostrophe by `user's` and `answer's`?

Comment: @Asylum yes, that is correct apostrophe usage for the (singular) possessive form

Comment: @MarcGravell: Oh...I seriously need to start to learn those rules one day...

Comment: @Asylum Yes, I am sure. It's the same case as in _the car's engine_. I was once confused by _today's news_ as I thought it was more correct to say _today news_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any flag-related downvote here does *not* incur a reputation change. It only applies once per post, and only affect's the *post's* score (not the owner's reputation).

Comment: I took the liberty to add this to the FAQ.